# In Fake News Detection ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()

Tags: python

I have the code as follows

```
 def createFeatureDictionary(self):
        # create dictionary for each class
        # key : class , value = {feature : frequency}
        categories = {}
        categoryCount = {}
        for yi in np.unique(self.y):
            categories[yi] = {}
            categoryCount[yi] = len(self.y[self.y == yi])
        # print(categoryCount)
        # print(self.X.shape)
        for j in range(self.docCount):
            for i in range(self.vocabularyCount):
                if self.X[j][i] != 0:
                    if i not in categories[self.y[j]]:
                        categories[self.y[j]][i] = 1
                    else:
                        categories[self.y[j]][i] += 1
                else:
                    categories[self.y[j]][i] = 0
        return categories, categoryCount
```

And the error as follows

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Owner\Desktop\Btech\source\run.py", line 137, in <module>
    selectTasks()
  File "C:\Users\Owner\Desktop\Btech\source\run.py", line 124, in selectTasks
    runModel(options[x](PARAMS[x]))
  File "C:\Users\Owner\Desktop\Btech\source\run.py", line 61, in runModel
    modelObj.fit(X_train, y_train)
  File "C:\Users\Owner\Desktop\Btech\source\NB.py", line 16, in fit
    self.categories, self.categoryCount = self.createFeatureDictionary()
  File "C:\Users\Owner\Desktop\Btech\source\NB.py", line 34, in createFeatureDictionary
    if self.X[j][i] != 0:
  File "C:\Python39\lib\site-packages\scipy\sparse\base.py", line 283, in __bool__
    raise ValueError("The truth value of an array with more than one "
ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all().
```

The type of X is a csr matrix and the error I am getting is such. I am trying to get a element of the matrix X.

Comment: There are hundreds of questions about that error message. What research have you done to resolve the problem?

Comment: Have you checked in a debugger what the value of `self.X[j][i]` is?

Answer (score 0):

`self.X[j][i]` is an array of values. `self.X[j][i] != 0` is an array of boolean values. What should be overall truth value?

If at least one `True` in the array should evaluate as `True`, use `numpy.any(self.X[j][i] != 0`)`.

If all should be `True` for the expression to be `True`, use `numpy.all(self.X[j][i] != 0`)`.

Comment: This does not work @RomanPavelka ."AttributeError: any not found" this error is thrown

Comment: @SanketKulkarni my bad, I messed up the signature. I fixed my answer.